# CAST and CONVERT in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it posible to CAST or CONVERT with string data type (method that takes data type parametar as string), something like:

```
CAST('11' AS 'int')
```

but not

```
CAST('11' AS int)
```

Comment: Not as is but you could use dynamic sql to do what *(I think)* you want.

Comment: You could write your own function with lots of IF @type = ...

Comment: I was trying to avoid that (make my own function), obviously I need to do my own function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use dynamic sql to achieve that:

```
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10) = 'int'
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(10) = '11'
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT CAST(' + @value + ' AS ' + @type + ')'

EXEC (@sql)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO with INT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18554)**
//  [with datetime](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18555)

Comment: How can I asign that result to a variable something like: DECLARE @variable int = EXEC(@sql)

Comment: @mcorluka `EXEC()` returns your result as table, you can store it in table variable, and, if needed, then select from table variable to int variable -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18595

Answer (score 6):

No. There are many places in T-SQL where it wants, specifically, a name given to it - not a string, nor a variable *containing* a name.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use dynamic sql, this should get you started:

```
DECLARE @datatype varchar(20)
DECLARE @sql varchar(4000)

SELECT @datatype = 'int'

SELECT @sql = 'PRINT CAST(''11'' AS '+@datatype+')'

exec (@sql)
```

Depending on what you exactly want/need you should read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), especially the parts about `sp_executesql`